# Discrete Math Binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics

Among the total of 26 members (15 women and 11 men) in the compound
be a group of five representatives appointed.

2a)In how many ways can the group be put together, if it is to contain
at least two women and at least one man?

b) In how many ways can, if there are two people, Mrs A and
Mr B, not both at the same time can be in the group of representatives?

Am I right that it is Binomial theorem but how many ways can I combine these?

Comment: Careful - this is not the binomial theorem, which talks about coefficients of the expansion of $(x+y)^n$. This is just using binomial coefficients - combinations, if you will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Number of groups with at least $2$ women and at least $1$ man:

$$\binom{15+11}{5}-\binom{1+11}{5}-\binom{15+0}{5}$$

> Number of groups without both Mrs A and Mr B:

$$\binom{15+11}{5}-\binom{15-1+11-1}{5-1-1}$$

Comment: Can you develop it further??

Comment: @JonasBo: Consider it a large hint. You're expected to show your efforts, not just write down a question, so here's your chance to do so...